# Function is not a function in onClick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to call a built-in function from every tr, when it's clicked. But I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.updateSelection is not a function at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick (index.html:1)`.

Here I render my HTML template.

```
    this.renderHtml = function () {
        return '<div class="widget-content widget-infotablewidget">' + 
                '<div class="infotable"></div>' +
        '</div>';
    };
```

And when certain conditions are passed I render a table.

```
this.updateTable = function (rows) {
        let appendix = '<table><thead><tr>';
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(rows[0]).length; i++) {
            appendix += '<th>' + Object.keys(rows[0])[i] + '</th>';
        }

        appendix += '</tr></thead><tbody>';

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            appendix += `<tr onclick="this.updateSelection(\'InfoTable\', ${i})">`;

            for (let cell in rows[i]) {
                appendix += '<td>' + rows[i][cell] + '</td>';
            }
            appendix += '</tr>';
        }

        appendix += '</tbody></table>';
        valueElem.append(appendix);
    }
```

I expect the function to update the selection, but get an error.

Comment: Where is the ***updateSelection*** function declaration?

Comment: the scope of 'this' is different for the element. Try defining updateSelection function somewhere in-scope.

Comment: It's predefined by the framework.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there should not be `this` in `onclick`

Comment: Reson 27 why generating a DOM by mashing together strings of HTML is awful. Use `createElement`, `addEventListener` and friends. It's much easier to manage.

Comment: How would I add event listeners on every row of the table then?

Comment: @GlebErmolaev — `for (...) { const tr = documment.createElement('tr'); tr.addEventListener('click', () => this.update(...)); /* etc*/ table_body.appendChild(tr); }` … in other words: use a loop just as you are **already doing**

Comment: @GlebErmolaev What framework is this? Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the easiest way to solve the problem was to define `var thisInstance = this;` and to work with `withInstance.updateSelection` not to conflict with different scopes.

Answer (score -1):

Try only calling function by name

```
appendix += `<tr onclick="updateSelection(\'InfoTable\', ${i})">`;
```

not by THIS keyword

Comment: Doesn't work since `updateSelection` is a function of `this`